# check checkbox and trigger change event javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to trigger change event and check checkbox from **javaScript not jQuery**.
I am having issues with jQuery because of this [Strange Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907645/jquery-chrome-and-checkboxes-strange-behavior).

What i used to do with jQuery is:

```
$('#laneFilter').prop('checked','true').trigger('change');
```

I want same to do with javaScript. This must be really simple but i could not find the way .
please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this. The easiest method is to just call that function:

```
var Chkinput = document.getElementById("laneFilter");
Chkinput .onchange();
```

If you need it to simulate the real event in full, or if you set the event via the html attribute or `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, you need to do a bit of feature detection to correctly fire the event:

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer will only work if the event listener is registered by setting the onchange property of the element.

If it is not the case, you can use:

```
    let element = document.getElementById('laneFilter');
    let event = new Event('change');
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me and also triggers a `change` event:

```js
const Chkinput = document.getElementById("laneFilter");
Chkinput.click();
```

(Tested in Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Works. Smart. How didn't I think of that :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="laneFilter"/>
<script> 
    checkbox = document.getElementById("laneFilter");
    checkbox.onclick = function(){ 
        alert('lol');
    };
    checkbox.checked = true;
</script>
```

should also work

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this answer, the modern way to trigger a change event is by using the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object.

```js
    const checkboxElement = document.getElementById('highlightTables');

    checkboxElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
      console.log("something changed");
    });

    const event = new Event("change");
    checkboxElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

See more information about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Answer (score -2):

I cut it to 2 then work fine

```
$('#laneFilter').prop('checked','true');
$('#laneFilter').trigger('change');
```

Comment: The question said not to use jQuery.

Answer (score -4):

Just call change function without parameters.

```
$('#laneFilter').change('change', function(){
        debugger
        ...
}).change();
```

it works in "jquery": "3.3.1"

Comment: The question stated explicitly not to use jQuery.