# Make checkbox functional with Enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the checkbox behave with the Enter key (when tabbed into) the same way it usually does with the space bar or when clicked. I cooked up a case where the checkbox is indeed being checked, but it then doesn't act like it should, i.e. I want it to display a previously hidden text and disappear itself. How can I achieve this? Adding something like `document.getElementById("myCheck").click()` doesn't work, though.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if( e.key === "Enter" && e.target.classList.contains('myCheck')){
        e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
    }
})

function myFunction() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked === true){
    form.style.display = "none";
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    form.style.display = "inline-block";
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" style="display:inline-block">
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox</label> 
</form>

<p id="text" style="display: none;">checkbox is checked</p>
```

Comment: A bit unconventional, but since the OP already came up with listening to `'keydown'`, within the handler function, the only thing left is to change the current `e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;` to `e.target.click();`. And maybe change listening from `'keydown'` to `'keyup'`

Comment: There's some good discussion on this subject plus examples of other solutions in this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676525/check-checkbox-and-trigger-change-event-javascript I would be kinda wary of this "enter" functionality though as its non-standard for keyboard users who will be used to the spacebar doing that job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is trigger the `click` event, that will check the box. If you manually set `checked` and then trigger `click` it will undo the manual setting.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if( e.key === "Enter" && e.target.classList.contains('myCheck')){
        //e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
        e.target.click()
    }
})

function myFunction() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked === true){
    form.style.display = "none";
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    form.style.display = "inline-block";
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

p {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" style="display:inline-block">
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox</label> 
</form>

<p id="text" style="display: none;">checkbox is checked</p>
```